# How to perform a string change within a FOR loop to elements in a list in Python Pandas

Tags: string, pandas, list, loops, element

So I have the following code:

```
x = 20
df = {}

for i in range(1,x):
    df['df_{}'.format(i)] = a bunch of operations

list1 = []

for j in range(1,x):
    list1.append(str('df_{}'.format(j)))

var1 = list1
print(var1)
```

Which prints the list `['df_1', 'df_2', 'df_3', ...]`

How can I get it to instead print the list `[df['df_1'], df['df_2'], df['df_3'], ...]`?

Comment: Does list comprehension solve the problem ? `[df[i] for i in var1]`

Comment: Why do you want this? what is the end goal, please create a sample dataframe and show us what exactly you want to do. In other words , please create an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @dzakyputra That prints out the actual dataframes, not a list of strings

Comment: @anky_91 I'm still new to Python......this was a block of intermediate code, after which I want to use this list of strings referencing dataframes, to iterate through and bulk merge them together. I just need this code to produce the right type of list in the format [df['df_1'], df['df_2'], .......]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this was a bit of confusion on my part about differentiating between different py objects.

The solution was to amend this piece of code above:

```
for j in range(1,x):
    df_list = df['df_' + str(j)]
    list1.append(df_list)

var1 = list1
print(var1)
```

I then reference var1 in subsequent code, which references all such df['df_(j)'] dataframes up to j within object var1.